# scala.swing.ListView: single/multiple selection

Tags: swing, scala, listview

How do I make `scala.swing.ListView` only allow a single item to be selected at a time?

I want to disable the default behavior of allowing multiple items to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most trivial way is to use `peer` property which is standard Swing `JList`:

```
listView.peer.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using following (Scala 2.9.0-1):

```
import swing.ListView
import swing.ListView.IntervalMode

val listView: ListView[String] = new ListView[String](Seq("a", "b", "c")) {
  selection.intervalMode = IntervalMode.Single
}
```